# Can't open files in Business Application Studio

Tags: sapui5, sap-business-application-studio

Every time I try to open a file in my project, I get the following error in the console (e.g. `Detail.view.xml`):

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to read file 'my-project/webapp/view/Detail.view.xml' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/user/projects/my-project/webapp/view/Detail.view.xml')

I set up the workspace and imported an existing project using a zip file.
I can create and open new files in the directory but the already existing "old" files cannot be opened.

Comment: You could use the terminal in BAS to see what the permissions are on the folders or files you're trying to access (`ls -la`). You could try making the access more permissive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there was no authorization to open the imported files. It can be fixed from the console.

```
chmod 777 -R /ui5folder
```